# copy files down the tree but only copy the files not the directories in target

Tags: file-copy

example I have 100 folders each with JPG and MOV files in them
I want to copy all the jpg into one folder and all the mov files into another

example

- `folder1` has `one.jpg` and `two.jpg` and `one.mov`
- `folder2` has `two2.jpg` and two2.mov
- `folder3` has `xxx.jpg` and `yyy.mov`

wanted result

- folder `jpgfiles` containing `one.jpg` `two.jpg` `two2.jpg` `xxx.jpg`
- folder `movfiles` containing `one.mov` `two2.mov` `yyy.mov`

Comment: Are the 100 files are direct subdirs of one parent? (in this case  `cp */*.jpg jpgfiles/ ; 
cp */*.mov movfiles/` )

Comment: This worked a treat i used the -p flag to preserve the creation date of the pictures so I can get them in the correct order for video processing later using cinelerra

Answer (score 3):

You can use find for this. You use the folder above the folder1, folder 2 etc and execute these commands there.

```
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec cp {} "jpgfiles/" +
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.mov" -exec cp {} "movfiles/" +
```

`/folder/` is the parent folder here. you need to modify it to your parent folder.

EDIT: Thanks to @godlygeek for pointing it out. If you'd like to copy only unique files, you can use the below

```
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'test ! -f jpgfiles/${0##*/} && { cp $0 jpgfiles/${0##*/}; }' {} +
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'test ! -f movfiles/${0##*/} && { cp $0 movfiles/${0##*/}; }' {} +
```

To copy the conflicting files with a unique file suffix:

```
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'test -f jpgfiles/${0##*/} && { cp $0 jpgfiles/${0##*/}.$RANDOM; }' {} +
find /folder/ -type f -name "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'test -f movfiles/${0##*/} && { cp $0 movfiles/${0##*/}.$RANDOM; }' {} +
```

Comment: You should use `+` instead of `\;`, and leave out the double quotes around `{}`, find handles spaces etc in file names, it doesn't create a shell instance when it invokes `mv` that might need the double quotes

Comment: @Anthon thanks. I`ve updated the answer.

Comment: I'd argue that you should quote `{}` - it's necessary in some shells (like zsh) and harmless in all others.  Also, it's worth noting that if there's a "foo.jpg" in two different subdirectories, only one of them is going to wind up in "jpgfiles" (obvious in retrospect, but probably worth noting explicitly - some files may be missing from "jpgfiles" afterwards).

Comment: thanks Guys for the rapid answer went with the cp solution as its easier for a newcomer!!